# Variable scope issues using Google (calendar) API

Tags: javascript, scope, google-calendar-api

I have a function that takes, as an argument, the response from the `gapi.client.calendar.events.list` call on the Google Calendar API.

I'm trying to iterate through that response, and `.push()` the elements to an array (`localEventList`). When I check the value of `localEventList` immediately after the for-loop, the events are stored in it, but when I check it outside of `.execute(function(events){...` function, the array is still empty. I've tried initializing the array to different values, and the array remains at the value it is initialized to.

I don't understand why the variable isn't staying mutated, since it's initialized in the overarching function call. Also, I'm not really clear on the purpose of the `.execute(...` call.

If anyone could clarify either of these two issues, I'd love you forever.

```
function parseEvents(calEventRequest){
var localEventList = new Array();

calEventRequest.execute(function(events){
    for(i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++){
        var item = events.items[i];
        var name = item.summary;
        var start = item.dateTime;
        localEventList.push(name);
    };
    // If I place a console.log(localEventList) here, the array is populated
}); 
console.log(localEventList); // But the call here displays an empty array. 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question  is `console.log()` will not wait for the `calEventRequest.execute()` function to be completed, if you are working with angularJs or any other js framework you can handle this operation with `defer` and `promise` like features which will wait for the api call and return the response only after finish.

the solution to your problem is to use a `callback` function after the forloop as below

```
// calling the parseEvents function 
parseEvents(calEventRequest,function(eventList){
console.log(eventList);
//this will print the array after for loop finished
})

function parseEvents(calEventRequest,callback){
var localEventList = new Array();

calEventRequest.execute(function(events){
    for(i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++){
        var item = events.items[i];
        var name = item.summary;
        var start = item.dateTime;
        localEventList.push(name);
    };
    if(callback)callback(localEventList);
    // If I place a console.log(localEventList) here, the array is populated
}); 
console.log(localEventList); // But the call here displays an empty array. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was the callback issue that got me. If anyone wanted to know even more, I found this thread helpful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: glad to know it helped u :)